# Depth search of a path in tree or graph data structures

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, tree, depth-first-search

I'm trying to creare a Tree or a Graph data structure that allow me to quickly search (depth search) if exists a specific path. In particular, starting from a list of strings:

```
ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
data.add("2.2.3.3.3");
data.add("2.3.4.3.4");
data.add("2.2.2.4.4");

String pathToFind1 = "2.3.4.X.4"
String pathToFind2 = "2.X.X.2.4"
String pathToFind3 = "2.3.X.4.4"
```

and a path to find (e.g., "X.2.X.4.4"), I would check if exist a path that:

- pathToFind1: links the nodes 2 (At depth 1), 3 (At depth 2), 4 (at depth 3), and 4 (at depth 5);
- pathToFind2: links the nodes 2 (At depth 1), 2 (at depth 4), and 4 (at depth 5);
- pathToFind3: links the nodes 2 (At depth 1), 3 (at depth 2), 4 (at depth 4), and 4 (at depth 5);

The value X represents a generic value.

```
/*
            2
          /   \
         2     3
        / \     \
       2   3     4
      /     \     \  
     4       3     3
      \       \     \     
       4       3     4     
*/

public static boolean findPath(String path) {
    //...
}

findPath(pathToFind1); //return true
findPath(pathToFind2); //return false
findPath(pathToFind3); //return false
```

I've thought to use a [Trie](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), but the main problem of this structure is that I should consider a full path to find (i.e., a path with all the elements).
Can you suggest a data structure or a solution to solve my problem? Notice that, it is not necessary to use a tree or graph, but my goal is to perform a quick search of paths.

Comment: trie can do the work. do a dfs when you get X. any issue with that?

Answer (score 0):

There are two main algorithms that you can use to do the work. I mean **DLS** and **IDS**.
These two are stable for Unconscious search. it means they search in specified level, not all of the graph and it is really quicker and needs less memory.
Try them may solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I cannot solve the problem with these algorithms.